# for/list annotations in typed/racket

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to add types to some numerical racket code in the hopes of making it faster, but I am stuck dealing with for/list macro expansion in the code below.

```
(: index-member ((Listof Any) (Listof Any) -> (Listof Index)))
(define (index-member xs ys)
  (filter-not negative?
              (for/list ([(ann i Index) (in-range (ann (length xs) Index))])
                (if (member (list-ref xs i) ys) i -1))))
```

This function returns a list of indexes foreach x which is a member of y.  It works in Racket, but I can't seem to get it past the type checker for Typed Racket.  Specifically, the error is:

> Type Checker: Error in macro expansion -- insufficient type information to typecheck. please add more type annotations in: (for/list (((ann i Index) (in-range (ann (length xs) Index)))) (if (member (list-ref xs i) ys) i -1))

Can you provide annotations that get this past the type checker and/or explain why these type annotations are insufficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key is to use the `for/list:` form instead since it allows you to add type annotations over the basic `for/list` form to give Typed Racket more guidance. I've made a few other adjustments to get the types to line up (e.g., using `filter` over `filter-not`, avoiding `in-range`, etc.):

```
#lang typed/racket

(: index-member ((Listof Any) (Listof Any) -> (Listof Index)))
(define (index-member xs ys)
  (filter index?
          (for/list: : (Listof Integer) ([i : Index (length xs)])
            (if (member (list-ref xs i) ys) i -1))))
```

This actually exposes a weakness in the type of `filter-not` (`filter` is smarter about the type of the list it returns), which I'll look into fixing.

Comment: I have a related question.  How can I handle the #:when clause in a for/first:?  I tried:  `(for/first: : Index ((i : Index 5) #:when (> i 3)) i)` but still need further annotations.

Comment: Unfortunately, `for` loops with `#:when` clauses are very finnicky in Typed Racket. One way to write that is `(first (for/list: : (Listof Index) ((i : Byte 5) #:when (> i 3)) i))`, but that's probably less efficient. You can also write the loop more manually. We have some ideas on how to make it more precise in the future.

Comment: `for/list:` is actually the deprecated form -- the standard `for/list` can be annotated with type information. See http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/special-forms.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fprims..rkt%29._for%29%29