# How should you type annotate mutually recursive functions in letrec in Typed Racket?

Tags: typed-racket

If I understand it correctly this is the correct way to annotate functions defined in a `letrec` in Typed Racket:

```
#lang typed/racket

(letrec ((is-even? (lambda ((n : Nonnegative-Integer))
                     : Boolean
                     (or (zero? n)
                         (is-odd? (sub1 n)))))
         (is-odd? (lambda ((n : Nonnegative-Integer))
                    : Boolean
                    (and (not (zero? n))
                         (is-even? (sub1 n))))))
  (is-odd? 11))
```

However this gives the error message:

```
Type Checker: insufficient type information to typecheck. please add more
              type annotations in: is-odd?
```

A workaround is this:

```
(local ((: is-even? : Nonnegative-Integer -> Boolean)
        (define (is-even? n)
          (or (zero? n)
              (is-odd? (sub1 n))))
        (: is-odd? : Nonnegative-Integer -> Boolean)
        (define (is-odd? n)
          (and (not (zero? n))
               (is-even? (sub1 n)))))
  (is-odd? 11))
```

Also forms of the legacy notation work such as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18513447/for-list-annotations-in-typed-racket) but I would expect to be able to annotate `letrec` using current notation too.

Answer (score 1):

You can put type annotations after the function names in the `letrec`, like this:

```
(letrec ([f1 : type1 expr1]
         [f2 : type2 expr2])
  body)
```

For your example, that looks like:

```
(letrec ([is-even? : (-> Nonnegative-Integer Boolean)
                   (lambda (n)
                     (or (zero? n)
                         (is-odd? (sub1 n))))]
         [is-odd? : (-> Nonnegative-Integer Boolean)
                  (lambda (n)
                    (and (not (zero? n))
                         (is-even? (sub1 n))))])
  (is-odd? 11))
```

Why does this work, but putting type annotations inside the `lambda` doesn't?

It's because making sure each `lambda` typechecks relies on the types of `is-odd?` and `is-even?` respectively. However, if you don't annotate the function-names directly, it can only try to infer those types by typechecking the lambdas.

Annotating the function-names directly means that it doesn't even have to look at the lambdas before it knows what types `is-even?` and `is-odd?` must have.

Comment: Your code works but it contains no more information about the types of the two functions than my version does so I don't see how your explanation holds up.

Comment: The difference is the order of typechecking vs. type-environment. In my code, the `letrec` form adds both `is-even? : (-> Nonnegative-Integer Boolean)` and `is-odd? : (-> Nonnegative-Integer Boolean)` to the environment before it even looks at the lambdas.

Comment: However, if the same amount of information is pushed into the lambdas, then the `letrec` has to start typechecking the lambdas in an environment where the types are unknown. The `is-even?` lambda gets the information about the type of `is-even?` because of its own type annotations. However the `is-odd?` hasn't been typechecked yet. It continues typechecking the `is-even?` lambda without going down to look at the type annotations on `is-odd?`. It doesn't do "both at once".